# How to bind an HTML Label to sqldatareader

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, runatserver

I am trying to bind a label to a datareader. With an input type="text" I am able to do something like this

```
MyName.Value = reader["MyName"].ToString();
```

-

```
 <label id="lblMyName" runat="server"></label>
```

I cant figure out how to bind this in the code behind as I dont see a ***lblMyName.Value*** or ***.Text***

Answer (score 1):

Use `lblMyName.InnerText`

But, any reason why you don't want to use asp.net Label control.

```
<asp:Label id="lblMyName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

With this `lblMyName.Text` works.